# ClassNotFoundException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.module.SimpleModule

Tags: json, maven, spring-batch, osgi-bundle, fasterxml

We are in the process of our platform upgrade and use apache Karaf 4.4.3 to deploy bundles.
A specific custom bundle has dependencies for fasterxml.jason in the pom.xml and also in the  tag of the maven-bundle-plugin as :
`<Import-Package>com.fasterxml.jackson.*</Import-Package>`.

The dependency version of jackson in the pom.xml is  2.12.7 :

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.12.7</version>
</dependency>
```

The dependency version of spring-batch-core is 4.3.7

Also, the jackson-databind jar with com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.module.SimpleModule is seen in the custom kar file after successful build.

Though the build is successful but the deployment of bundle on Karaf fails with the error :

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: **com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.module.SimpleModule not found by org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-batch-core** [353]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.findClassOrResourceByDelegation(BundleWiringImpl.java:1591) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.access$300(BundleWiringImpl.java:79) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.loadClass(BundleWiringImpl.java:1976) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loa
```

Comment: The stacktrace is truncated. Does the stack trace show some code path in Spring Batch that is not finding the Jackson library? Does not seem to be a problem related to Spring Batch itself, it is rather related to the custom jar org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-batch-core